# Ajuda com pesquisa em campo data - android

Tags: android

Boa tarde tenho Uma tabela no banco com um campo data, preciso juntar os valores do campo diferença entre uma data especifica, por exemplo:  os ultimos 10 minutos, os ultimos 60 minutos, os ultimos 7 dias, mas não estou conseguindo teria como me ajudarem, segue o código da pesquisa

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:sss");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());


public String nomeTabela() {
    String Pesquisa = "";
    ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
    ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
    objConexao.db_connect_string = "flexvale.hopto.org:1433";
    objConexao.db_name = "FlexPortaCom";
    objConexao.db_userid = "sa";
    objConexao.db_password = "flextelecom";
    Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);



    if (conn == null) {

        Pesquisa = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";

    } else



    if (conn != null) try {


        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        String queryString = "select SUM(DIFERENÇA) as somaMes from TOTALIZADOR WHERE NID = 252 AND DATAHORA >=' "+  currentDateandTime  +  " -30 '   AND DATAHORA <= '"+ currentDateandTime +" '";
         ResultSet rs;

        rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);

        if (rs.next()) {

            Pesquisa = rs.getString("somaMes");

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Pesquisa = e.getMessage();


    }
    return Pesquisa ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A resposta depende de seu SGBD. Vou dar um exemplo para o SQL Server para o intervalo de 30 dias:

```
SELECT
   SUM(DIFERENÇA) as somaMes 
FROM TOTALIZADOR 
WHERE (NID = 252)
AND (DATAHORA BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())
```

Para retornar a data atual no MySQL, a função se chama NOW().

Vale a pena olhar a documentação e chegar outras funções como TIMEADD().

Boa Sorte.